# How to make live youtube video plugin for kodi

Tags: python, youtube, kodi

I am starting to get into python and learn some Kodi development as well.

I looked at this tutorial http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=248774, and it is great for static youtube channels.

My question is, how can I make a Kodi video plugin that streams live content from a live youtube feed?

If anyone has a code example or have link to a tutorial that would be great. So far I have not found one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video is a nice tutorial of how to do this. It also has a nice upload utility for real time management.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0xqyL0XxAo